# python open applications through your program

Tags: python, operating-system

I want my program to open iTunes during runtime. How do I implement this ?
I looked around for answers but didn't get any concrete complete answers. Till now, all I know is I could use the `os` module and then call the `os.system()` function to open iTunes. If this is right, what goes into the brackets ?
I have a Mac OS X machine.

Comment: Which operating system? They each different `api's` and methods of doing such tasks.

Comment: @enginefree Hey buddy ! It's a Mac OS X

Comment: Take a look at `macpython` and this link http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/AppleScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this on Mac OS X will be to use the `open` command:

```
os.system("open -a iTunes")
```

There are undoubtedly other ways of doing this (e.g, using the Cocoa/Python bridge), but this is the simplest.

Comment: Hey thanks ! Worked like a charm. What would I need to input if I want to enter a particular song (say x.mp3) through iTunes ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python) should be able to help you.

From the article linked above...

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
os.chdir( 'c:\\documents and settings\\flow_model' )
os.system( '"C:\\Documents and Settings\\flow_model\\flow.exe"' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) if you want to simply run an executable.

[`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) run the command in a subshell, which generates an unnecessary extra process and slightly different behavior depending on the operating system/console used (for example `cmd.exe` have different escaping than `bash`)

Answer (score 0):

Read `subprocess`, is better than `os.system` in your case.

Subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html