# How to start an executable from a variable path

Tags: python, variables, path, os.system

I'm not able to start an executable from a variable path. I've tried:

```
os.system(destPath + '/BHC.exe')
os.system(destPath/BHC.exe)
```

the destPath is set correctly and the BHC.exe is in there.

How can I start the external program?

Comment: What is the output of `print destPath + '/BHC.exe'`?

Comment: 1) Do not use `os.system` but `subprocess.call` instead 2) Use `os.path.join` instead of manually joinining the file paths: `import os, subprocess; subprocess.call([os.path.join(destPath, 'BHC.exe')])`.

Comment: On Windows, `os.system` uses Windows components like `cmd.exe` which don't understand paths with forward slashes in them. Assuming `destpath` doesn't have any, try `+ '\\BHC.exe'` (or better yet do as @Erica suggests).

Comment: @martineau `os.system` understands forward slashes for absolute paths but not relative paths. We'll know what's going on when OP finally answers @Undo's question. Why people post questions and then ignore requests for more information is the puzzling part!

Comment: Thanks for your information (and solution :-)! It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to avoid any slash confusion:

```
os.system(os.path.join(destPath, 'BHC.exe'))
```

If that doesn't resolve the problem, further troubleshooting is best answered by [running an outside program (executable) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python)

Comment: @tdelaney: But obviously doesn't, hence the question.

Comment: @martineau this answer Is extremely unlikely to fix the problem. Whatever causes OPs problem will still fail.mIt should be a comment.

Comment: @Erica Thank you! The `os.path.join` did the right thing :)