# QGIS: How to run R directly in python console?

Tags: python, r, qgis

I have been using QGIS python console to automate my needs. I've used a few processing algorithms (such as distance matrix) to work on my vector layers which outputs csv files.I need R to work on these files before bringing them back to my python console as variables.

Is there a way I can run R directly through the python console (maybe using packages such as rpy2?)

Comment: If you have an R script, you can run it as you would from a command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line

Comment: to run commands like Rscript, I have to be in R in the terminal/python console first, right?
I am able to run R through my windows cmd just by typing 'r', but have been unable to do the same through the console in qgis... 

So how do i do it the same way as cmd?

Comment: You can run Rscript as an external program ("Rscript yourscript.R"). See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can easily interact with a R instance in the QGis python console using [`rpy2`](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org).
Try these following lines of code in the QGIS python console:

```
>>> import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
>>> rinterface.set_initoptions((b'rpy2', b'--no-save'))
>>> rinterface.initr()
0
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
```

You can now interact with R like this :

```
>>> robjects.r("""seq(1,12);""")
<IntVector - Python:0x7fa5f6e4abd8 / R:0x769f4a8>
[       1,        2,        3, ...,       10,       11,       12]
```

Or import some libraries for example :

```
>>> rutils = importr("utils")
>>> rgraphics = importr('graphics')
```

Take a look at the [documentation of Rpy2](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org), I have successfully used these methods to run some personals scripts or some libraries installed from the CRAN (running multiple statements in `robjects.r("""...""")` and grabbing the output in a python variable to use in QGIS).

(If i remember well, on windows I had to set some environnement variables first, like `R_HOME` or `R_USER` maybe)

Also, if you haven't seen it, take a look at this page of the QGIS documentation : [**17.31. Use R scripts in Processing**](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/processing/r_intro.html). It offers a convenient way to use your existing R script with some slight add.

Comment: I've installed rpy2 and it works from cmd.... i can import the package...
But haven't been able to run the same through the QGIS python console-

I tried- `import rpy2` or `import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface`

It throws the error- 
_Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named rpy2_

Comment: Also, R Scripts won't do for the kind of application I'm looking for- too much back and forth between R and python

Comment: ok, problem solved... just had to add the relevant folder for rpy2 in sys.path