# Python: subprocess not writing output files

Tags: python, subprocess

Using Python's `subprocess.call`, I am trying to invoke a C program that reads an input file on disk, and creates multiple output files. Running the C program from terminal gives the expected results, though `subprocess.call` does not.

In the minimal example, the program should read the input file in a scratch folder, and create an output file in the same folder. The locations and names of the input & output files are hardcoded into the C program.

```
import subprocess


subprocess.call('bin/program.exe') # parses input file 'scratch/input.txt'
with open('scratch/output.txt') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

This returns:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scratch/output.txt'`

What am I doing wrong?

Using `subprocess.check_output`, I see no errors.

EDIT:
So I see the subprocess working directory is involved. The C executable has hardcoded paths for input/output relative to the exe (ie, '../scratch/input.txt'), but the `subprocess.call()` invocation required paths *relative to the python script*, not the exe. This is unexpected, and produces very different results from invoking the exe from the terminal.

Comment: I will suggest to use "import commands"; using this you will also get output of you C program(you can run it normal way you runs in gcc), and if failure the status code will change.
eg. output = commands.getstatusoutput("gcc test.c")

Comment: @abhijeetmote the `commands` module is made obsolete by the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

subprocess.call('bin/program.exe') # parses input file 'scratch/input.txt'
if not os.path.isfile('scratch'):
    os.mkdir('scratch')
with open(os.path.join('scratch','output.txt'), 'w') as f:
    f.write('Your message')
```

You have to open the file in a mode. Read for example. You will need to join the path with os.path.join().

You can create a folder and a file if they don't exist. But there will bo nothing to read from. If you want to write to them, that can be acheived like shown above.

Comment: If file mode isn't specified, it should default to read. Besides, the problem isn't in reading the  output file, it's that the output isn't created.

Comment: You can't read from a file that doesn't exist - regardless, I updated my answer to create a file and folder that you can write to.

Comment: I appreciate that while a non-existent file can't be read, my concern is with *why* the output file isn't being created. Invoking the C program from the terminal creates the expected output file in the scratch folder, while invoking it though `subprocess.call` creates no output file. The locations and names of the input & output files are hardcoded into the C program. `subprocess.check_output` also yields no errors, unlike if I remove the input file, in which case `check_output` contains the C program's relevant error message.

Comment: Apologies, try `print subprocess.call()` or do a check `if subprocess.call()!=0 print 'failure'` it also may need more time to finish running the exe. In that case, you can wait for it to finish with `while subprocess.call != 0: pass`

Comment: My understanding of `subprocess` is that by default it waits for the subprocess to complete, before proceeding. Besides, if I reduce the script to only invoke the subprocess, and remove the attempt to read the output, it still completes, with no output file created.

Comment: have you tried `subprocess.call(["C:\pathToYourProgram\yourProgram.exe"])`

Comment: All the [answers from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python) use the `[]`notation.

Comment: Yes, [] makes no difference.