# Running IDL Compiled EXE in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to execute a compiled ENVI IDL executable within Python 2.7, but have yet to figure out how to do it. My code looks like this:

```
import os, subprocess

filepath = "C:\\RVT_1.3_Win64.exe"

os.system(filepath)
```

I have tried most of the options from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python) post. However, I get a "Path\To\My\Python\RVT_1.3_Win64.ini doesn't exist. INI filename must be the same as EXE filename."

I have also tried running a small BAT file from Python with no results.

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.call(filepath)`?

Answer (score 0):

To execute a batch file

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/K","pgm1.bat"])
```

I tried it with the following batch file (called `pgm1.bat` in the same directory as the python program--use full paths otherwise)

```
echo "Hello"
echo "World"
```

Use `"/K"` if you want the console to persist after running the batch file (so you can see the output, but you will have to close it manually).  Use `"/C"` if you want to console to exit immediately after the batch file has executed.

For an executable, you may try to execute directly with `call()`.

If you have problems with required files, you may try to change the current working directory with `os.chdir()`.