# passing arguments to x-executable file from within a python script

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

im trying to call an executable (application/x-executable) file with arguments from within a python script.
I have seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python) but i still cant get it to work.
when calling this file through the terminal i simply use the form:

```
location/of/file < output
```

meaning i call the function with these 2 arguments.
im trying to do the following from my python script:

```
import subprocess

preprocess_path = "file_location"
subprocess.call([preprocess_path, '<', 'output.sas'])
```

but this doesnt seem to work.
Any suggestions out there? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using Popen instead of call

Comment: I have found it always good practice to call the file within the project, by using ./filename.output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `subprocess.Popen` and using the keyword argument `stdin` with the input file open:

```
import subprocess

preprocess_path = "file_location"

with open('output.sas', 'r') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([preprocess_path], stdin = f)
    proc.wait()
```