# Anaconda prompt, running same script multiple times

Tags: python, anaconda

Firstly, I have very limited experience with programming. So please bear with me.

I am using a custom software, called [deformcyto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvBWz.png),  made for my lab which can only be started via `anaconda` prompt. I need to call the same program multiple times but with different inputs. Can I write a [python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfnYj.png) which would keep calling the program with new arguments?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python), if your program is an executable.

```
os.system(r"C:\youdir\..\yourprogram.exe")
```

You can also write a bash script or a powershell script and start the program multiple times with different arguments.

Comment: May be helpful to use string substitution in your example.  `os.system("deformcyto %s" % imageOfCellsOne)`