# Entering a command to an opened Command Prompt window with python script

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, command-prompt, external, executable

I have been trying enter couple of commands on a command window with python script. I was able to open the .exe file by checking the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python/51248766?noredirect=1#comment89476874_51248766).

However, now my code:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'filepath')
os.system("start /B start filepath\application.exe")
```

opens the application and it asks for an input file name, then it will ask for output file name. Is there a way to do that. This will be used for ArcGIS so it needs to be done in python 2.7.

I checked all related questions but did not find the answer. I would appreciate it very much if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! It was easier than I thought but I needed lots of research. This code for python 2.7 which may differ for other versions.

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir(r'filepath')
subprocess.check_call([r"filepath\your_.exe_app", 'your_input'])
```