# How to run C# project in the backend of a Python Flask app?

Tags: c#, python, flask

I'm running into a situation in which I have these separate parts that I want to make into a web app:

1. the UI written in Javascript
2. the Python Flask framework
3. a C# project that I want to execute and get output when a user clicks some button on the front-end

The first two parts are already integrated but I have no idea how to compile&build a C# project from Python. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the C# project a web project (e.g. WebAPI) or a console app?

Comment: The C# project is a standalone console app

Comment: assume that the exe is in the same server and it is a Windows Server, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python