# How to extract text from pdf in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.7, pypdf, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract text from a PDF file using Python. My main goal is I am trying to create a program that reads a bank statement and extracts its text to update an excel file to easily record monthly spendings. Right now I am focusing just extracting the text from the pdf file but I don't know how to do so.

What is currently the best and easiest way to extract text from a PDF file into a string? What library is best to use today and how can I do it?

I have tried using PyPDF2 but everytime I try to extract text from any page using extractText(), it returns empty strings. I have tried installing textract but I get errors because I need more libraries I think.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("January2019.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

This prints empty strings when it should be printing the contents of the page

edit: This question was asked for a very old PyPDF2 version. New versions of PyPDF2 have improved text extraction a lot

Comment: Does the pdf have textual content?

Comment: How about searching through the questions already on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf2

Comment: Yes there is actual text all over the pdf that I can highlight.

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica PyPDF2 improved text extraction a lot. It's now pretty good. Please give it a shot :-)

Comment: Also, the quote you gave from the docs is no longer applicable (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using tika worked for me!

```
from tika import parser

rawText = parser.from_file('January2019.pdf')

rawList = rawText['content'].splitlines()
```

This made it really easy to extract separate each line in the bank statement into a list.

Comment: finally found a solution that worked for me. All of these other PDF scanners did not work for my use case, and that may be due to the formatting of the actual PDF. However, this tika package worked flawlessly. You will need to install the latest version of Java, as well as the Java tika server.jar file. Once you download the java tika server jar file you can run from cmd on windows, java -jar java-tika-server.jar to run the local server, then this package will work for python

Comment: It is best thing I found, I have tried `PyPDF2`, `pdfminer` but is suits by purpose,because it gives line by line output.

Comment: I can confirm that tika is very nice choice. I like it for the simplicity and ability to extract links from pdf.

However, for me I found even better way to do the job from Windows command line:
"gswin64c -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o pdf2text.txt "sample.pdf""
...provided you have gswin64c.exe installed and the path set correctly. It was installed on my machine, I just had to set the PATH.

Answer (score 52):

I have tried many methods but failed, include PyPDF2 and Tika. I finally found the module [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) that is work for me, you also can try it.

Hope this will be helpful to you.

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open('pdffile.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
pdf.close()
```

Comment: Could you loop this solution for multiple folders with multiple pdfs and transform the results in dataframe or alike? I have a question about it if you could kindly look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224627/how-to-extract-text-from-pdfs-in-folders-with-python-and-save-them-in-dataframe

Comment: excellent package, much better than PyPDF2, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for a maintained, bigger project, have a look at [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). Install it with `pip install pymupdf` and use it like this:

```py
import fitz

def get_text(filepath: str) -> str:
    with fitz.open(filepath) as doc:
        text = ""
        for page in doc:
            text += page.getText().strip()
        return text
```

Comment: you saved me from losing my sanity. I'm trying to open pdfs with arabic, Chinese, non English language and your solution preserved the characters, thank  you

Comment: This solution seems more effective than PyPDF2.

Answer (score 3):

PyPDF2 is highly unreliable for extracting text from pdf . as pointed out [here](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/) too.
it says :

> While PyPDF2 has .extractText(), which can be used on its page objects
>   (not shown in this example), it does not work very well. Some PDFs
>   will return text and some will return an empty string. When you want
>   to extract text from a PDF, you should check out the PDFMiner project
>   instead. PDFMiner is much more robust and was specifically designed
>   for extracting text from PDFs.

1. You could instead install and use [pdfminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) using

   `pip install pdfminer`
2. or you can use another open source utility named `pdftotext` by [xpdfreader](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html). instructions to use the utility is given on the page.

you can download the command line tools from [here](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)
and could use the pdftotext.exe utility using `subprocess` .detailed explanation for using subprocess is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

PyPDF2 does not read whole pdf correctly. You must use this code.

```
    import pdftotext

    pdfFileObj = open("January2019.pdf", 'rb')


    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(pdfFileObj)

    # Iterate over all the pages
    for page in pdf:
        print(page)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution in Windows 10, Python 3.8

Example test pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUfQAlvq5hA9kz2c9CyJADiY3KpY3-Vn/view?usp=sharing

```
#pip install pdfminer.six
import io

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    '''Convert pdf content from a file path to text

    :path the file path
    '''
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()

    with io.StringIO() as retstr:
        with TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec,
                           laparams=laparams) as device:
            with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
                interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
                password = ""
                maxpages = 0
                caching = True
                pagenos = set()

                for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp,
                                              pagenos,
                                              maxpages=maxpages,
                                              password=password,
                                              caching=caching,
                                              check_extractable=True):
                    interpreter.process_page(page)

                return retstr.getvalue()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(convert_pdf_to_txt('C:\\Path\\To\\Test_PDF.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdftables_api
import os

c = pdftables_api.Client('MY-API-KEY')

file_path = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Documents\\PDFTablesCode\\"

for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        c.xlsx(os.path.join(file_path,file), file+'.xlsx')
```

Go to https://pdftables.com to get an API key.

CSV, format=csv

XML, format=xml

HTML, format=html

XLSX, format=xlsx-single, format=xlsx-multiple

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/). You can extract either plain text or decoded text containing "pdf markdown":

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""

try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in terminal execute command: `pip install PyPDF2`

```
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader("mypdf.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will be exactly what you are looking for:

```
import requests, time, datetime, os, threading, sys, configparser
import glob
import pdfplumber

for filename in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    pdf = pdfplumber.open(filename)
    OutputFile = filename.replace('.pdf','.txt')
    fx2=open(OutputFile, "a+")
    for i in range(0,10000,1):
        try:
            page = pdf.pages[i]
            text = page.extract_text()
            print(text)
            fx2.write(text)
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e)
    fx2.close()
    pdf.close()
```